# Nested form in activeadmin not saving updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

I have a nested form in ActiveAdmin for these models (a :class_section has_many :class_dates):

```
class ClassDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :class_section
  validates :start_time, :presence => true
  validates :end_time, :presence => true

end
```

and

```
class ClassSection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :class_course
  has_many :class_dates
  belongs_to :location

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :class_dates
end
```

Everything seems to be in the right place when I look at the form. However, when I update a class_date, it doesn't save.

```
ActiveAdmin.register ClassSection do

  permit_params :max_students, :min_students, :info, :class_course_id, :location_id

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :class_course, member_label: :id_num
      f.input :min_students, label: "Minunum Students"
      f.input :max_students, label: "Maxiumum Students"
      f.input :location
    end
    f.inputs do
      f.input :info, label: "Additional Information"
    end
    f.inputs "Dates" do
      f.has_many :class_dates, heading: false do |cd|
        cd.input :start_time, :as => :datetime_picker
        cd.input :end_time, :as => :datetime_picker
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end

  index do
    column :class_course
    column :location
    default_actions
  end

  filter :class_course
  filter :location

  show do |cs|
    attributes_table do
      row :class_course do
        cs.class_course.id_num + " - " + cs.class_course.name
      end
      row :location
      row :min_students, label: "Minunum Students"
      row :max_students, label: "Maxiumum Students"
      row :info, label: "Additional Information"
    end

    panel "Dates" do
      attributes_table_for class_section.class_dates do
        rows :start_time, :end_time
      end
    end
    active_admin_comments
  end 

end
```

Here is the ActiveAdmin file for ClassDates:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ClassDate, as: "Dates" do

  permit_params :start_time, :end_time, :class_section_id

  belongs_to :class_section

end
```

Can you see a reason why it's not saving properly?

**UPDATE:** I added the following code to the AA and it seems to work now:

```
controller do
  def permitted_params
    params.permit!
  end
end
```

Let me know if there is a better solution. Thanks.

**UPDATE 2:** There is one lingering problem however. I am unable to delete ClassDates using this form.

Comment: shouldn't you permit the nested params being handed over?

Comment: I added some code to do this and it seems to work. (I'll update)

Comment: It works with the exception of providing a way to delete ClassDate records.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to permit nested parameters, but you should **never** use `params.permit!`. It's extremely unsafe. Try this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ClassSection do
  permit_params :max_students, :min_students, :info, :class_course_id, :location_id, 
                class_dates_attributes: [ :id, :start_time, :end_time, :_destroy ]

  form do |f|
    # ...
    f.inputs "Dates" do
      f.has_many :class_dates, heading: false, allow_destroy: true do |cd|
        cd.input :start_time, :as => :datetime_picker
        cd.input :end_time, :as => :datetime_picker
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end

  # ...
end
```

The configuration (and `permitted_params`) of your `ClassDate` admin panel has nothing to do with the permitted parameters within the `ClassSection` admin panel. Treat them as separate controllers within the app.

Adding the `allow_destroy: true` option to the `has_many` call will add a checkbox to the form to allow you to delete a class time upon form submission.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helps a lot. The change to the permissions works. The 'allow_destroy: true' does give me the check_box, but it doesn't seem to work. I check the box and click 'Update Class section" and the class_date is still there.

Comment: Are there any messages in your logs regarding unpermitted parameters? You need to include the `:_destroy` in the `class_dates_attributes` array, as well as `accepts_nested_attributes_for :class_dates, allow_destroy: true` in the `ClassSection` model.

Comment: Adding "allow_destroy: true" to the ClassSection model did the trick. Thank you for your help!

Comment: even though this is a fairly old post, it would be useful to incorporate the gist of the above comments into the answer proper