# belongs_to id not being set activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I have two models: `Asssessment` and `Question` which are organized like this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :assessment

class Assessment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions
```

I'm trying to create an activeadmin (ver 1.0.0) interface to create assessments and add questions to them.
So far I've tried making a questions tab:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Question do
  permit_params :question_text, :question_type, :scale_min, :scale_max

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Question Information" do
      f.input :assessment, :as => :select, :collection => Assessment.non_daily_assessments
      f.input :question_type, :as => :select, :collection => Question.human_readable_question_types.keys
      f.input :question_text, :input_html => {:rows => 2, :cols => 10}
      f.input :scale_min
      f.input :scale_max
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

`non_daily_assessments` simply returns a subset of all assessments
I am able to select from a list of assessments, but when I save the question and am taken to the "view question" page the question's `assessment_id` is empty.

Similarly, if I create an assessments tab:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Assessment do
  permit_params :name, :questions

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Assessment Information" do
      f.input :name, :input_html => {:rows => 1, :cols => 10}
      f.has_many :questions, :allow_destroy => true, :heading => 'Questions' do |qf|
        qf.input :question_type, :as => :select, :collection => Question.human_readable_question_types.keys
        qf.input :question_text, :input_html => {:rows => 2, :cols => 10}
        qf.input :scale_min
        qf.input :scale_max
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

I am able to go to a particular assessment and start adding questions, but when I reload the page they're gone. Going into the console I see that the questions were created, but their `assessment_id`'s are `nil` just like through the question tab.

What is a correct way to create an activeadmin interface for a `belongs_to` `has_many` relationship?

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your permit_params are incomplete. Have a look at this answer: [Nested form in activeadmin not saving updates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21410005/163640)

You need to add `:assessment_id` to the permit_params in the Question section, and if you want to be able to edit questions with the assessments, you're probably missing the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions` in the Assessment model, and you'll also need to change the permit_params in the Assessment section to something like

`permit_params :name, questions_attributes: [:id, :question_type, :question_text, :scale_min, :scale_max]`