# Use permit params in active admin controller from different modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am using active admin for business model, I want to use other model in this also "business_images" and i want to access business_image params in business controller how can i do this?

Rails 4

```
permit_params :name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Business do
  permit_params :name, business_image_attributes: [:any_attr] 
end
```

read this for more info:

http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html

Answer (score 0):

I never use this before, you can add permitted params of nested resource like so:

```
permit_params :name, business_image_attributes: [:image]
```

Reference: [Nested form in activeadmin not saving updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410005/nested-form-in-activeadmin-not-saving-updates)